# split a number by total number onChange input

Tags: arrays, reactjs

My requirement is to split a to num in input so that it should not exceed total sum  and for eg : if I enter 50 in any field other fields should have 25 each for 2 input values if there are 3 fields.

here is code sandbox for work on [codesand box](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-germain-w9zmm?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Why the other components that receive the split value has to be input element, any specific reasons ?

Comment: Have you tried anything, it would be helpful to know what you have tried and provide suggestion based on that.

Comment: bcs if i change any input value amount should split equal on rest of the fields

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-germain-w9zmm?file=/src/App.js updated my code sandbox but onchange is not affecting

Comment: What is the logic behind adding the input element. Is there a prop value thats passed that specifies how many input controllers are present ? Or do we have any controller, where on click/ event trigger the input element increase/decrease ?

Comment: What about the state, if we consider input element as dynamic then we can't consider this `const [num, setNum] = useState({ num1: "", num2: "", num3: "" });` . We would be constrained

Comment: yes it there is prop , how many times you want to split your amount , for now we just keep a constant for 3 inputs

Comment: I wanted just like splitwise app, total amount can be divided unequally amoung the given input fields

Answer (score 1):

Remove `useEffect` hook, the dependency for the hook is `num` and inside the callback of `useEffect` num is once again updated with `setNum`. This is a big no-no.

I suggest following changes to the `handleChange` callback

```js
function handleChange(evt) {
    const value = evt.target.value;
    const inputElements = document
        .getElementById("App")
        .getElementsByTagName("input");
    let numberOfInputElements = 1;
    if (numberOfInputElements !== null) {
        numberOfInputElements = inputElements.length - 1;
    }

    setNum((inputNum) => {
        for (const key in inputNum) {
            if (inputNum.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                inputNum[key] = value / numberOfInputElements;
            }
        }
        return { ...inputNum, [evt.target.name]: value };
    });
}
```

Link to [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/winter-http-xeq1u?file=/src/App.js:161-717) for complete code.

But I understand your requirement is slightly different from the problem statement.

Comment: it should be splitted  from the total amount. for eg: total amt =100 and if user inputs 50 in any fields other 2 fields should be 25 , 25 for three input fields jsx.

Comment: The above mentioned change is for the question. From the comments, I understood that there is a change in what you are expecting.